# According to dropdown change on input keydown certain functionality should be done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is one dropdown and inputbox. If Aadhar is selected in dropdown i am assigning keydown event for input box which takes numeric only. In case of PASSPORT i am changing keydown event which takes alphanumeric characters.

```js
 function changeDocumentType(pthis) {
    //dropdown change
    var htmlid = "#" + pthis.id;
       var doctype = $(htmlid+':selected').val();
       populateValidations(doctype,"docId");
    }

    function populateValidations(doctype,inputId){
      $("#"+inputId).removeAttr("onkeydown");
         $("#"+inputId).removeClass("onlyNumeric");
         $("#"+inputId).removeClass("alphabetNumeric");
        if(doctype === "1"){
        //aadhar
            $("#"+inputId).addClass("onlyNumeric");
            $("#"+inputId).attr("onkeydown", "return inputOnlyNumberTablet(this,event,12)");
         }
         if(doctype === "2") {
         //passport
              $("#"+inputId).addClass("alphabetNumeric");
              $("#"+inputId).attr("onkeydown", "return inputOnlyAlphaNumericTablet(this,event,10)");
        }
    }

    function inputOnlyAlphaNumericTablet(pthis, event, length){
 $('.alphabetNumeric').on('input', function(event) {
            if (pthis.value.length <= parseInt(length, 10)) {
                pthis.value = pthis.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');
            } else {
                pthis.value = pthis.value.substr(0, pthis.value.length - 1);
            }
        });
    }
    }

    function inputOnlyNumberTablet(pthis, event, length){
 $('.onlyNumeric').on('input', function(event) {
            if (pthis.value.length <= parseInt(length, 10)) {
                pthis.value = pthis.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            } else {
                pthis.value = pthis.value.substr(0, pthis.value.length - 1);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="docId" type="text" value="" enabled="enabled" >
    <select style="" value="" enabled="enabled" onchange="changeDocumentType(this)" id="DocumentListFile">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Aadhar ID</option>
    <option value="2">PassPort</option>
    </select>
```

If once aadhar is selected for passport also it is taking only numeric input. This code is return for android device. Any solution??
Thanks.

Comment: you can use a single validation function, all you have to do is change the pattern to be used when the option changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the other keydown listener before binding the new one else you get multiple listeners each time you perform your dropdown,

**Simply removing the attribute from the element doesn't unbind the event.**

This isn't a complete copy/paste answer. It's an example, to which you can tweak to your needs. I've just taken the part of your code that assigns the listener and changed it.

```
function populateValidations(doctype,inputId){
    var inp = $("#"+inputId); // get this once. Easier if there is a name change etc
    inp.unbind('keydown'); // unbind any keydown event that may exist
    inp.removeClass("onlyNumeric");
    inp.removeClass("alphabetNumeric");
    if(doctype === "1"){
         //aadhar
         inp.addClass("onlyNumeric");
         // add your keydown
         inp.keydown(function(){ return inputOnlyNumberTablet(this,event,12);});
    }

    if(doctype === "2") {
        //passport   
        inp.addClass("alphabetNumeric");
        inp.keydown(function(){return inputOnlyAlphaNumericTablet(this,event,10);});
    }
}
```